# C error saying expression is not assignable?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

So I'm writing a program that takes a string input of three colors of a resistor band and calculates it's resistance.

I've taken the input, and this function uses strcmp (or strcasecmp) to compare the string with a list of colors. However, I am getting a compiler error saying "statement is not assignable", directly referring to the if/elseif statements.

I have the list in an array, but for the purpose of this I just used a string. Here is the function I am getting errors from. Do I maybe have to add a for or while loop?

```
char calculate_first_resistance(char color1[8])
{
    g = strlen(color1)-1;
    if( color1[ g ] == '\n')
        color1[g] = '\0';


    if (strcmp(color1, "black")=NULL)
    {
        band1=0;
    }
    else if (strcmp(color1, "brown")=NULL)
    {
        band1=10;
    }
    else if (strcmp(color1, "red")=NULL)
    {
        band1=20;
    }
    else if (strcmp(color1, "orange")=NULL)
    {
        band1=30;
    }
    else if (strcmp(color1, "yellow")=NULL)
    {
        band1=40;
    }
    else
    {

    }

    printf("%d", band1);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Why did you tag as Java and C?

Comment: @Arc676 less wondering, more editing.... this is definitely not java, and not relevant to GNU or OSX people

Comment: Oh dear... the `=` sign is assignment; and `==` is comparisson. Now you figure out why the compiler issues "expression is not assignable".

Answer (score 7):

```
if (strcmp(color1, "black")=NULL)
```

should be

```
if (strcmp(color1, "black")==0)
```

Edit: Compare to 0 not Null. See post of Arc676

Comment: Use == if you want to compare two values like you did in
if( color1[ g ] == '\n')
Use = if you want to assign a value to a variable like you did in
color1[g] = '\0';

Answer (score 3):

You put an assignment instead of a comparison in your `if` conditions:

```
(strcmp(color1, "brown")=NULL)
```

Use `==` to compare

```
(strcmp(color1, "brown") == 0)
```

Use 0 because that's what `strcmp` returns if the strings are equal (see [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp))

Answer (score 1):

Other users already noted that you error was to assign instead of compare in your if.

In these case, you got lucky that the compiler gave you error, but there are cases where the compiler might not warn you.

For example, if you write

`if ( band1 = 0)`

you would be assigning the value 0 to the variable band1, instead of comparing them.

That why many people prefer to write like this:

`if ( 0 == band1 )`

In this, case, if you forget the second =, it will give you an error, because the statement

`if ( 0 = band1 )` 
is **invalid**